# Writing my own OBJ parser that loads the data in VBOs, how to re-order data to match single index list?

Tags: android, parsing, opengl-es-2.0, vbo, wavefront

I've been trying to convert an OBJ parser that I wrote previously that used display lists to use VBOs instead, and have attempted to see if I could figure out the issue myself without any outside help, but now I think I have been looking at the code too long and am unable to find any errors.

This is an Android App, through OpenGLES 2.0, and I end up with some triangles up on the screen, but not in the correct places at all. I have a feeling that my attempt to get all of the elements of each face based on a single list of indices is incorrect and I just end up throwing everything out of order, but I am unable to find my error.

Essentially, since the OBJ format gives a separate index for the vertex, the texture coordinate and the normal vector, I end up with 3 lists of data that are completely out of order from each other, but the VBO references each part based on a single list of indices.

Here is my code, in order to help someone help me:

OBJToolkit:

```
public class OBJToolkit {
    public static Mesh loadOBJ(String modelLocation) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Location searched for model: " + modelLocation);

        ArrayList<Float> allVertices = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<Float> allTextureCoors = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<Float> allNormals = new ArrayList<Float>();

        ArrayList<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(modelLocation)));

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to read the contents of the model");
        while (reader.ready())
        {
            String line = reader.readLine();

            if (line == null)
                break;

            if (line.startsWith("v "))
            {
                allVertices.add(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]));
                allVertices.add(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]));
                allVertices.add(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("vt "))
            {
                allTextureCoors.add(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]));
                allTextureCoors.add(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("vn "))
            {
                allNormals.add(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]));
                allNormals.add(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]));
                allNormals.add(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("f "))
            {
                Face f = new Face();
                String[] lineArray = line.split(" ");

                for (int index = 1; index < lineArray.length; index++)
                {
                    String[] valueArray = lineArray[index].split("/");
                    f.addVertexIndex(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[0]));
                    if (valueArray.length > 1)
                        f.addTextureIndex(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[1]));
                    if (valueArray.length > 2)
                        f.addNormalIndex(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[2]));
                }
                faces.add(f);
            }
        }
        reader.close();

        ArrayList<Float> verticesInOrder = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<Integer> indicesInOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Float> textureCoorsInOrder = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<Float> normalsInOrder = new ArrayList<Float>();

        int counter = 0;
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to reorganize each point of data");
        for (Face f : faces)
        {
            for (int value : f.vertexIndices)
            {
                verticesInOrder.add(allVertices.get(value));
            }

            for (int value : f.textureIndices)
            {
                textureCoorsInOrder.add(allTextureCoors.get(value));
            }

            for (int value : f.normalIndices)
            {
                normalsInOrder.add(allNormals.get(value));
            }
            indicesInOrder.add(counter);
            counter++;
        }

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Vertices");
        printFloatArrayList(verticesInOrder);
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Indices");
        printIntegerArrayList(indicesInOrder);
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Texture Coordinates");
        printFloatArrayList(textureCoorsInOrder);
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Normals");
        printFloatArrayList(normalsInOrder);

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to create the VBOs");
        mesh.createBuffers(floatListToFloatArray(verticesInOrder), integerListToShortArray(indicesInOrder), null, floatListToFloatArray(textureCoorsInOrder));
        return mesh;
    }

    public static void printFloatArrayList(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += value + ", ";
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static void printIntegerArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += value + ", ";
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static float[] floatListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Float");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (float i : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = i;
            counter++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static short[] integerListToShortArray(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Integer");
        short[] returnArray = new short[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = (short)i;
            counter++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

Mesh class:

```
public class Mesh { 
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    private FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer indicesBuffer;
    private int numOfIndices = -1;
    private float[] rgba = new float[] {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mTextureBuffer;
    private int mTextureId = -1;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private boolean mShouldLoadTexture = false;

    public float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, rx = 0, ry = 0, rz = 0;

    public Mesh() {

    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl)
    {
        //Log.d("Mesh", "About to render mesh");
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
        gl.glColor4f(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);
        if (colorBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
        }

        if (mShouldLoadTexture)
        {
            loadGLTexture(gl);
            mShouldLoadTexture = false;
        }

        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        }

        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        gl.glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(rz, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, numOfIndices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        }
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

    public void setTexture(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public void createBuffers(float[] vertices, short[] indices, float[] colors, float[] textureCoords)
    {
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Vertices: " + floatArrayToString(vertices));
        setVertices(vertices);
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Indices: " + shortArrayToString(indices));
        setIndices(indices);
        if (colors != null)
            setColors(colors);
        setTextureCoordinates(textureCoords);
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Texture Coors: " + floatArrayToString(textureCoords));
    }

    public String floatArrayToString(float[] array)
    {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            returnString += array[i];
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    public String shortArrayToString(short[] array)
    {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            returnString += array[i];
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    protected void setVertices(float[] vertices)
    {
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        verticesBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
        verticesBuffer.position(0);
    }

    protected void setIndices(short[] indices)
    {
        ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indicesBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
        indicesBuffer.put(indices);
        indicesBuffer.position(0);
        numOfIndices = indices.length;
    }

    protected void setColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
    {
        rgba[0] = red;
        rgba[1] = green;
        rgba[2] = blue;
        rgba[3] = alpha;
    }

    protected void setColors(float[] colors)
    {
        ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
        cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuffer.put(colors);
        colorBuffer.position(0);
    }

    protected void setTextureCoordinates(float[] textureCoords)
    {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoords.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mTextureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoords);
        mTextureBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void loadBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        mShouldLoadTexture = true;
    }

    private void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl)
    {
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        mTextureId = textures[0];
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mBitmap, 0);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something blatantly wrong or over-complicated that I have just been unable to spot?

I thank anyone that is willing to offer their input.

Comment: This is a lot of code to sift through, but I know the OBJ file format uses indices beginning with 1 (not 0 as in most programming languages arrays). Your comment about the triangles being in the wrong places made me think of this.

Comment: Oh man, I'm not sure how I managed to miss that one, but that is definitely not something I knew about when I wrote this! Thank you for that, although I'm not sure yet whether it solved my problem entirely or was just part of it.

Comment: Glad to help -- I know I have (repeatedly) lost hours over that indexing issue.

Comment: A few suggestions, I've done all this too and have it working but after a LONG time. I reviewed the code but don't see anything obviously wrong. Check your obj data, often times I'd forget to triangulate the data, so there would be four sets of indices where I was expecting just 3. Also, if you have multiple objects in the .obj file things SHOULD line up, but perhaps not. In fact, what I'd suggest is starting with a VERY basic obj file, 1 or 2 tri's, a basic texture, and basic normals. Then step through the code, and make sure things are going where you expect them too in your structures.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! It turns out that was a major part of the issue, I had forgotten to check the "Triangulate Faces" option when exporting as an OBJ from Blender. Another issue was that in my re-ordering each array to fit the order that the vertices were in, I also re-ordered the vertices, effectively reversing the work I had already done. Once I fixed these issues, everything shows up correctly, but I think the normals on the backmost faces are backwards. While the cube is rotating, one side will light up while the other does not. What's the easiest way to draw the vertex normals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work, for the most part. I wasn't keeping the related data for each vertex together well enough so by the time it needed to be rendered, it was all out of order. 
The parser as of now supports vertices, normals and texture coordinates, although with mildly detailed meshes it hits the maximum heap size and gets stuck in a very long garbage collection loop. I created the suzanne monkey head in Blender, subdivided it once with smoothing and exported that as an OBJ. It did load, but it took about 20 minutes.

Here is the source, I'm sure it will help someone as I could not manage to find code that read an OBJ file and sent it to the graphics card in the form of VBOs, WITH normals and texture coordinates working:

```
public class OBJToolkit {
    private static ArrayList<String> parseOBJ(String modelLocation) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(modelLocation)));
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(reader.ready())
        {
            lines.add(reader.readLine());
        }
        reader.close();
        reader = null;
        return lines;
    }

    public static Mesh loadOBJ(String modelLocation) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Location searched for model: " + modelLocation);

        ArrayList<Vector3f> allVertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Vector2f> allTextureCoords = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        ArrayList<Vector3f> allNormals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();

        ArrayList<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        ArrayList<String> lines = parseOBJ(modelLocation);

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to read the contents of the model");
        for (String line : lines)
        {
            if (line == null)
                break;

            if (line.startsWith("v "))
            {
                allVertices.add(new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("vt "))
            {
                allTextureCoords.add(new Vector2f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]),Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("vn "))
            {
                allNormals.add(new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]), Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3])));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("f "))
            {
                //Log.d("OBJToolkit", line);
                Face f = new Face();
                String[] faceVertexArray = line.split(" ");

                for (int index = 1; index < faceVertexArray.length; index++)
                {
                    String[] valueArray = faceVertexArray[index].split("/");

                    if (allTextureCoords.size() > 0)
                        f.addVertex(new Vertex(allVertices.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[0]) - 1), allNormals.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[2]) - 1), allTextureCoords.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[1]) - 1)));
                    else
                        f.addVertex(new Vertex(allVertices.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[0]) - 1), allNormals.get(Integer.valueOf(valueArray[2]) - 1), new Vector2f(0, 0)));
                }
                faces.add(f);
            }
        }

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of vertices: " + allVertices.size());
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of normals: " + allNormals.size());
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Number of texture coords: " + allTextureCoords.size());

        lines = null;
        allVertices = null;
        allNormals = null;
        allTextureCoords = null;

        ArrayList<Vector3f> VBOVertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Vector2f> VBOTextureCoords = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        ArrayList<Vector3f> VBONormals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        ArrayList<Integer> VBOIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "About to reorganize each point of data");
        int counter = 0;
        for (Face f : faces)
        {
            for (Vertex v : f.vertices)
            {
                VBOVertices.add(v.position);
                VBONormals.add(v.normal);
                VBOTextureCoords.add(v.textureCoord);
                VBOIndices.add(counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        faces = null;

        mesh.createBuffers(vector3fListToFloatArray(VBOVertices), integerListToShortArray(VBOIndices), null, vector2fListToFloatArray(VBOTextureCoords), vector3fListToFloatArray(VBONormals));

        VBOVertices = null;
        VBONormals = null;
        VBOTextureCoords = null;
        VBOIndices = null;
        return mesh;
    }

    public static void printFloatArrayList(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static String floatArrayToString(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        return strToPrint;
    }

    public static String vector3fArrayToString(ArrayList<Vector3f> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (Vector3f v : list)
        {
            strToPrint += v.x + ", ";
            strToPrint += v.y + ", ";
            strToPrint += v.z + ", ";
        }
        return strToPrint;
    }

    public static void printStringArray(String[] list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (String s : list)
        {
            strToPrint += s + ",";
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static void printIntegerArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        String strToPrint = "";
        for (float value : list)
        {
            strToPrint += (value + ", ");
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", strToPrint);
    }

    public static float[] floatListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Float> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Float");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Float i : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = i.floatValue();
            counter++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static short[] integerListToShortArray(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Integer");
        short[] returnArray = new short[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = (short)i;
            counter++;
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static float[] vector3fListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Vector3f> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Vector3f");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size() * 3];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Vector3f v : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = v.x;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.y;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.z;
            counter++;
        }

        return returnArray;
    }

    public static float[] vector2fListToFloatArray(ArrayList<Vector2f> list)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Converting ArrayList Vector2f");
        float[] returnArray = new float[list.size() * 2];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Vector2f v : list)
        {
            returnArray[counter] = v.x;
            counter++;
            returnArray[counter] = v.y;
            counter++;
        }

        return returnArray;
    }
```

Vector3f:

```
public class Vector3f {
    public float x, y, z;

    public Vector3f()
    {
        setTo(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Vector3f(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        setTo(x, y, z);
    }

    public void setTo(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public float lengthSquared()
    {
        return x*x + y*y + z*z;
    }

    public float length()
    {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(lengthSquared());
    }

    public Vector3f add(Vector3f v)
    {
        return new Vector3f(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z);
    }

    public Vector3f addAndSet(Vector3f v)
    {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
        z += v.z;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3f crossProduct(Vector3f v)
    {
        return new Vector3f(y * v.z - z * v.y,
                z * v.x - x * z,
                x * v.y - y * v.x
                );
    }

    public Vector3f negate()
    {
        x *= -1;
        y *= -1;
        z *= -1;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3f normalize()
    {
        float l = length();

        return new Vector3f(x / l, y / l, z / l);
    }

    public float dotProduct(Vector3f v)
    {
        return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
    }

    public float angleBetween(Vector3f v)
    {
        float dls = dotProduct(v) / (length() * v.length());
        if (dls < -1f)
            dls = -1f;
        else if (dls > 1.0f)
            dls = 1.0f;
        return (float)Math.acos(dls);
    }

    public Vector3f scale(float scale)
    {
        return new Vector3f(x * scale, y * scale, z * scale);
    }

    public Vector3f scaleAndSet(float scale)
    {
        x *= scale;
        y *= scale;
        z *= scale;
        return this;
    }


}
```

Vector2f:

```
public class Vector2f {
    public float x, y;

    public Vector2f()
    {
        setTo(0, 0);
    }

    public Vector2f(float x, float y)
    {
        setTo(x, y);
    }

    public void setTo(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float lengthSquared()
    {
        return x * x + y * y;
    }

    public float length()
    {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(lengthSquared());
    }

    public Vector2f add(float x, float y)
    {
        return new Vector2f(this.x + x, this.y + y);
    }

    public Vector2f addAndSet(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector2f negate()
    {
        x *= -1;
        y *= -1;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector2f normalize()
    {
        float l = length();
        return new Vector2f(x / l, y / l);
    }

    public float dotProduct(Vector2f v)
    {
        return x * v.x + y * v.y;
    }

    public float angleBetween(Vector2f v)
    {
        float dls = dotProduct(v) / (length() * v.length());
        if (dls < -1f)
            dls = -1f;
        else if (dls > 1.0f)
            dls = 1.0f;
        return (float)Math.acos(dls);
    }

    public Vector2f scale(float scale)
    {
        return new Vector2f(x * scale, y * scale);
    }

    public Vector2f scaleAndSet(float scale)
    {
        x *= scale;
        y *= scale;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Mesh:

```
public class Mesh { 
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    private FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer indicesBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer normalsBuffer;
    private int numOfIndices = -1;
    private float[] rgba = new float[] {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mTextureBuffer;
    private int mTextureId = -1;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private boolean mShouldLoadTexture = false;

    public float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, rx = 0, ry = 0, rz = 0;

    public Mesh() {

    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl)
    {
        //Log.d("Mesh", "About to render mesh");
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
        gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalsBuffer);
        gl.glColor4f(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);
        if (colorBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
        }

        if (mShouldLoadTexture)
        {
            loadGLTexture(gl);
            mShouldLoadTexture = false;
        }

        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        }

        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        gl.glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(rz, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, numOfIndices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null)
        {
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        }
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

    public void setTexture(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public void createBuffers(float[] vertices, short[] indices, float[] colors, float[] textureCoords, float[] normals)
    {
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Vertices: " + floatArrayToString(vertices));
        setVertices(vertices);
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Indices: " + shortArrayToString(indices));
        setIndices(indices);
        if (colors != null)
            setColors(colors);
        if (textureCoords != null)
            setTextureCoordinates(textureCoords);
        if (normals != null)
            setNormals(normals);
        Log.d("MeshCreateBuffers", "Texture Coors: " + floatArrayToString(textureCoords));
    }

    public String floatArrayToString(float[] array)
    {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            returnString += ", " + array[i];
        }
        if (returnString.length() > 2)
            return returnString.substring(2);
        else
            return returnString;
    }

    public String shortArrayToString(short[] array)
    {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            returnString += ", " + array[i];
        }
        if (returnString.length() > 2)
            return returnString.substring(2);
        else
            return returnString;
    }

    protected void setVertices(float[] vertices)
    {
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        verticesBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
        verticesBuffer.position(0);
    }

    protected void setIndices(short[] indices)
    {
        ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indicesBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
        indicesBuffer.put(indices);
        indicesBuffer.position(0);
        numOfIndices = indices.length;
    }

    protected void setColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
    {
        rgba[0] = red;
        rgba[1] = green;
        rgba[2] = blue;
        rgba[3] = alpha;
    }

    protected void setColors(float[] colors)
    {
        ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
        cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuffer.put(colors);
        colorBuffer.position(0);
    }

    protected void setTextureCoordinates(float[] textureCoords)
    {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoords.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mTextureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoords);
        mTextureBuffer.position(0);
    }

    protected void setNormals(float[] normals)
    {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(normals.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        normalsBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        normalsBuffer.put(normals);
        normalsBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void loadBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        mShouldLoadTexture = true;
    }

    private void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl)
    {
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        mTextureId = textures[0];
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mBitmap, 0);
    }
}
```

Face:

```
public class Face {
    ArrayList<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

    public Face()
    {

    }

    public void addVertex(Vertex vertex)
    {
        vertices.add(vertex);
    }
}
```

Vertex:

```
public class Vertex {
    public Vector3f position, normal;
    public Vector2f textureCoord;

    public Vertex(Vector3f pos, Vector3f norm, Vector2f textCoord)
    {
        position = pos;
        normal = norm;
        textureCoord = textCoord;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        MyGLSurfaceView view = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        OpenGLRenderer renderer = new OpenGLRenderer();
        view.renderer = renderer;
        //renderer.plane.loadBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        view.setRenderer(renderer);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements OnGestureListener, OnTouchListener
{
    OpenGLRenderer renderer;
    GestureDetector detector;

    float lastX = 0, lastY = 0;

    float onDown = 0, onUp = 0;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        detector = new GestureDetector(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
    {
        detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "X: " + me.getX());
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Y: " + me.getY());
        return super.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me)
    {
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onTouch event");
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "X: " + me.getX());
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Y: " + me.getY());
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            lastY = me.getY();
        }
        else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            renderer.moveMesh(me.getY() - lastY);
        }
        /*
        if (lastX == 0)
        {
            lastX = me.getX();
        }
        if (lastY == 0)
        {
            lastY = me.getY();
        }
        Log.d("OBJToolkit", String.valueOf((me.getY() - lastY) * 0.1f));
        renderer.moveMesh(me.getY() - lastY);
        */
        lastY = me.getY();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onDown Event");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onFling Event");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onLongPress Event");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onScroll Event");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onShowPress Event");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("OBJToolkit", "Registered onSIngleTapUp Event");
        return false;
    }

}
```

OpenGLRenderer:

```
public class OpenGLRenderer implements Renderer
{
    //SmoothColoredSquare smoothSquare = new SmoothColoredSquare();
    //Cube cube = new Cube(1, 1, 1);
    public Mesh plane;

    public float meshMoveSpeed = .05f, planePosition = 0f;

    float zNear = 0.01f, zFar = 1000.0f, fieldOfView = 45.0f, size;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "About to attempt to load model");
        try {
            plane = OBJToolkit.loadOBJ(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/testModel.obj");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("FNF", "testModel.obj not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("IOE", "testModel.obj not found IOE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //.z = -7.7f;
        //plane.rx = -10;
        gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT0);
        float ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
        float diffuseColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
        float lightPosition[] = {-2f, 5f, -2f, 1f};
        gl.glLightfv(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, ambientColor, 0);
        gl.glLightfv(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseColor, 0);
        gl.glLightfv(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_POSITION, lightPosition, 0);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        gl.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        //Reset viewport
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        //Select projection matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        size = (float) (zNear * Math.tan((fieldOfView / 180.0f) * Math.PI) / 2.0f);
        gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (width / height), size / (width / height), zNear, zFar);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        //Reset projection matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        //Calculate aspect ratio of window
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        //GLU.gluLookAt(gl, -5f, 2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        //Select modelview matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        //Reset modelview matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        //Clear the screen before drawing
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //plane.ry += 2f;
        //plane.rz += 2f;

        plane.x += meshMoveSpeed;
        plane.z = planePosition;
        if (plane.x > 3f)
        {
            meshMoveSpeed *= -1;
        }
        else if(plane.x < -3f)
        {
            meshMoveSpeed *= -1;
        }

        //Reset the current position held by OpenGL, otherwise the
        //camera will be pushed farther and farther back every frame
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        //Move the camera backwards in order to actually see the face
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0f, -15f);

        plane.draw(gl);
    }

    public void moveMesh(float distance)
    {
        planePosition += distance * 0.05f;
    }
}
```