# How can I convert an ArrayList<Vector3f> to a ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, arraylist, nio, bytebuffer

I'm trying to create a `TriangleIndexVertexArray` with JBullet, but to do this I need to parse a `ByteBuffer` of all the vertices in the model.

I have got an `ArrayList<Vector3f>` of all the vertices in the model.

How can I parse this list of `Vector3f`'s to a `ByteBuffer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follow

Declaring your vertices

```
ArrayList<Vector3f> verticesnew = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
```

Set your vertices

```
vertices.add( new Vector3f(someVertice) );
```

Get Float buffer from vertices:

```
// There are 3 floats needed for each vertex (x,y,z)
int bufferSize = vertices.size() * 3 * Float.SIZE;
FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( bufferSize ).order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() ).asFloatBuffer();

// Copy the values from the list to the direct float buffer
for ( Vector3f v : vertices )
    verticesBuffer.put( v.x ).put( v.y ).put( v.z );
```

Comment: I specifically need to pass a ByteBuffer, and not a FloatBuffer. Is that an issue?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492161/convert-floatbuffer-to-bytebuffer) to convert FloatBuffer to ByteBuffer.

Comment: If i got what you mean in your question, you need a `FloatBuffer`. Because `ByteBuffer` is just an intermidiate to get your result. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651638/writing-my-own-obj-parser-that-loads-the-data-in-vbos-how-to-re-order-data-to-m) also.